# Finding a way to revert JQuery UI dialog dialog's function

Tags: jquery-ui-dialog

I am trying to find a way to revert a jQuery UI dialog's dialog() call.

What I am doing in my app first is calling dialog on a div as such:

```
$('#dialog').dialog({
...options
});
```

Then once the user presses the close button, I would like the div tag and its content to reappear again at the same place it was before calling dialog() but not in the jQuery dialog.

I've tried this :

```
$('#dialog').dialog('close'); 
$('#dialog').show();
```

but it doesn't work. It seems that the #dialog's content is emptied when dialog('destroy') is called.

Any ideas?

Thanks,
Jimmy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps what you can do is to duplicate #dialog to an new div, and dialog() that one, leaving the original untouched.

Comment: Ok thanks, I will try that with a html() or clone() function that will certainly work. I wondered however if there could be a revertOnClose option out there, that would have been great to work on the same div.

Answer (score 0):

In fact it was a bit more difficult than a straight html() or append() since in my div I had a jQuery datatables component + a bunch of other custom events. So I first had to deeply clone its children with all the events then call fadeIn() fadeOut() in the right place. So here I go:

The HTML (the #dialog children get cloned Inside the #dialog2 div):

```
    <div id="main">
                <div id='dialog'>
                    <input id='input1' type="text"></input>
                    <input id='input2' type="text"></input>
                    <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" class="display" id="example" width="100%">
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th>Rendering engine</th>
        <th>Browser</th>
        <th>Platform(s)</th>
        <th>Engine version</th>
        <th>CSS grade</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
    <tr class="odd gradeX">
        <td>Trident</td>
        <td>Internet
             Explorer 4.0</td>
        <td>Win 95+</td>
        <td class="center"> 4</td>
        <td class="center">X</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="even gradeC">
        <td>Trident</td>
        <td>Internet
             Explorer 5.0</td>
        <td>Win 95+</td>
        <td class="center">5</td>
        <td class="center">C</td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
<tfoot>
    <tr>
        <th>Rendering engine</th>
        <th>Browser</th>
        <th>Platform(s)</th>
        <th>Engine version</th>
        <th>CSS grade</th>
    </tr>
</tfoot>
    </table>

                </div>
                <div id='dialog2' style='display:block;'>
                </div>





                <button id="open">Detach Me</button>
```

The JavaScript:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){

$("#dialog").children().clone(true, true).appendTo($("#dialog2"));
    $('#dialog2').hide();
    $('#open').click(function(){
         $('#dialog2').fadeOut();
         $("#dialog").dialog({
          width: 1000,
          height:800,
          close : function(){
             $('#dialog2').fadeIn();
             return true;
          }
         });
    });

 this.datatable = $('table').dataTable({
   "fnRowCallback": function(nRow, aData, iDisplayIndex, iDisplayIndexFull) {
        $(nRow).on('click', function(){
            $(this).addClass('selected', true);
        });
        }
  });
});

</script>
```